# How to replace underscore to space by using t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, updates

```
SELECT [Name]
      ,[Code]
      ,case when len([ParentCode]) = '' then [Code] else [ParentCode] end as [ParentCode]
      ,case when len([Descr])=0 then [Code] else [Descr] end as [Descr]
      ,[Cumulative]
      ,[Expense]
      ,[Accts]
      ,[Admin]
      ,[Assessment]
      ,[Balance]
      ,[Fiber]
      ,[GL]
      ,[LV]
      ,[Slush]
  FROM [KR].[pl].[Accounts]
```

Currently I have that query, but I want to change the part where data contains underscore instead space in ParentCode, and Code columns. Ex (slush_Code)
how can i modify this query to work?

Comment: `len([ParentCode]) = ''` . how did this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`replace()` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql):

```
SELECT REPLACE(ParentCode,'_',' ')
```

For example:

```sql
SELECT [Name]
  ,[Code]
  ,case 
       when len([ParentCode]) = 0 then REPLACE(Code,'_',' ') 
       else REPLACE(ParentCode,'_',' ') 
   end as [ParentCode]
  ,case when len([Descr]) = 0 then REPLACE(Code,'_',' ') 
       else [Descr] 
   end as [Descr]
  ,[Cumulative]
  ,[Expense]
  ,[Accts]
  ,[Admin]
  ,[Assessment]
  ,[Balance]
  ,[Fiber]
  ,[GL]
  ,[LV]
  ,[Slush]
FROM [KR].[pl].[Accounts]
```