# SQL Server : replace space with underscore in select one filed

Tags: sql-server, select

In a Microsoft SQL Server `SELECT` command I am trying to replace the spaces with no space so that the name of the database that responds changes from '**DB NAME 01**' to '**DBNAME01**' here is my current command:

```
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Code;Name;Ledgers'
    DECLARE @command VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @command = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')
                    USE [?]

                    SELECT CG_Num ,CG_Intitule ,DB_NAME() AS [Current Database]
                    FROM [dbo].[F_COMPTEG]'

    EXEC SP_msforeachdb @command
END
```

the result:

```
34860100;Mobilier;EI ELYTB L2
34860100;Cheptel;EI ELYTB L3
34870100;Emballages récupérables;EI ELYTB L4
```

the good result:

```
34860100;Mobilier;EIELYTBL2
34860100;Cheptel;EIELYTBL3
34870100;Emballages récupérables;EIELYTBL4
```

Thanks

I did a search on the internet and on this site without finding a similar case, I would like some help

Comment: `REPLACE(DB_NAME(), ' ', '')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace underscore to space by using t-sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640025/how-to-replace-underscore-to-space-by-using-t-sql)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

This T-SQL should work

```
REPLACE(DB_NAME(), ' ', '_')
```